# Installed app with weird problem: Text entry doubles keystrokes - EExxaammppllee

Tags: transmission, text, 14.10

I installed the app [transgui](https://code.google.com/p/transmisson-remote-gui/) on a couple of machines with Ubuntu 14.10. On one (and only one) of the machines, each and every text field exhibits the strange behaviour of all keystrokes counted double - EExxaammppllee .

apt-get purge and reinstall of the app didn't help. If I copy the settings file transgui.ini over from one of the other machines, the point-and-click part works just fine. This is the only issue, everything else on this pc works as it should.

How can I fix this strange behaviour / what could be the root cause?